# Received Data is nil when calling a https-function of google cloud function

Tags: javascript, swift, google-cloud-functions

I´m trying my first app with google cloud functions. I have a simple javascript function like this:

```
exports.updateisavaiable = functions.https.onCall((data) => {
  const ref = admin.database().ref('/appinfo/actualversion');

  ref.once("value", function (snapshot) {
    
    const actualversion = String(snapshot.val());
    const currentversion = data.currentversion;

    console.log(currentversion);
    console.log(actualversion);

    let updateavailable;

    if (actualversion > currentversion) {
      updateavailable = true;
    } else {
      updateavailable = false;
    }

    console.log(updateavailable);
    return(updateavailable);
  });
});
```

When I´m calling this function in my swift app with the following code I just get "nil":

```
private func updateisavailable() {
        //Überprüft ob ein Update verfügbar ist
        
        let functions = Functions.functions()
        
        functions.httpsCallable("updateisavaiable").call(["currentversion": CVersion.GetCleanVersion()]) { (result, error) in
            //Wenn Update verfügbar, dann zeigt er eine Meldung
            if let updateavailable = result?.data as? Bool {
                if updateavailable {
                    CAlert.showBasicAlert(title: "Update available", message: "There is an update of schnitzelwithme available. Please download it in the app store to be sure, that you can use all functions of schnitzel with me!", vc: self)
                }
            } else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "error could not be load")
            }
        }
    }
```

In the console i get the correct values (actualversion = "0.6.3", currentversion = "0.6.2", updateisavailable = true).

I don´t know whats the problem with these functions and why the value is nil.

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually setting `data`, try this:

```
return({data: updateavailable});
```

Comment: What version of `firebase-functions` are you using? You could try to call the function using Postman (or similar) and see the actual output.

Comment: i just can find the version of firebase-tools (V 9.1.0) where can i find the version of firebase-functions?
If you mean the pod firebase-functions in the xcode-project, it´s 7.0.0

Comment: You can find it in your `package.json`.

Comment: Thank you for that information. It´s 3.11.0

Comment: When i change my currentversion to  "const currentversion = '0.6.2' and call the function in the browser i get:
{"error":{"message":"Bad Request","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}